# Transfer named ranges structure to treeview (treestructure)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, treeview, vsto

I have an **Excel sheet** with many **named ranges**. Now I want to visualize the **hierarchical structure of all named ranges in a treeview** (with VSTO / C#). What would be the best and effective way to **parse** the named ranges hierarchy structure (ranges can consist again of ranges, so there is a father/child relationship) and transfer into a treeview (maybe with an **XML structure** beetween the Excel and the treeview representation).

Comment: What would you see if they intersect but not completely?